# Selecting data within multiple DATE (year) ranges into named columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I have to select data from a SQL Sever table for multiple date range i.e.

```
1990-1994,  1992-1996,  1994-1998,  1996-2000,  1998-2002,  2000-2004,  
2002-2006,  2004-2008,  2006-2010,  2008-2012,  2010-2014
```

I have used this query to get data without DATE ranges i.e.

```
SELECT 
    aid, research_area_category_id, 
    CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [research_area],
    COUNT(*) [Counting]
FROM 
    sub_aminer_paper
GROUP BY 
    CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)), aid, research_area_category_id
HAVING 
    aid = 12403 
ORDER BY 
    Counting DESC
```

This gives output as in image i.e.

[image]

Now for each DATE range using `WHERE` clause, I have to show data in respective column for DATE ranges. Whereas I have used this query i.e.

```
SELECT 
    aid, research_area_category_id, 
    [research_area] = CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)), 
    [Counting] = COUNT(*),
    [1990 - 1994] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 1994 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [1992 - 1996] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1992 AND 1996 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [1994 - 1998] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1994 AND 1998 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [1996 - 2000] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [1998 - 2002] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1998 AND 2002 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2000 - 2004] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2004 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2002 - 2006] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2002 AND 2006 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2004 - 2008] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2004 AND 2008 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2006 - 2010] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2006 AND 2010 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2008 - 2012] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2008 AND 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [2010 - 2014] = SUM(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    sub_aminer_paper
WHERE 
    aid = 2937  
    AND p_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2014            
GROUP BY
    aid, CAST(research_area AS VARCHAR(100)), research_area_category_id
ORDER BY aid ASC, Counting DESC
```

And this query outputs this:

[image]

but I need `research_area_category_id` value under (1990-1994, 1992-1996, 1994-1998.....so on) these columns. E.g. in `1990 - 1994` column, it should display respective `research_area_category_id` i.e. `1`, `1` and `32` instead of `Counting` i.e. `1`, `1` and `1`, similarly it should display `33` instead of `2` in `1998 - 2002` column and vice versa.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to add your date ranges as columns?

Comment: @FelixPamittan yeah absolutely

Comment: `HAVING` should only be used on **aggregates**, e.g. `COUNT`, `MAX`, `AVG` etc. - not on basic expressions like this - use `WHERE aid = 12403` instead

Comment: @FelixPamittan please review your answer

Comment: The standard way to create data-driven columns is with CASE statements.   Is there some reason you can't use them here?

Comment: @TabAlleman I have used but not getting desired output

Comment: @TabAlleman Can you direct how to do this as I need value of `research_area_category_id` in year-wise intervals (columns)

Comment: Please edit your post with your CASE statements, so we can see why they didn't work.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have edited my post with CASE statements, also shown the output with this query and asked for desired output.

Comment: @TabAlleman haven't you seen the query yet?

Comment: So instead of SUM(1 or 0) in each CASE, just put research_area_category_id (ELSE 0 or NULL, whichever you want to display).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89825/discussion-between-taufel-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab Alleman has already alluded to the best approach here within the comments, but I'm going to be cheeky and add it as an answer.

You are clear that you want to display values from the `research_area_category_id` column in your pivoted date columns. Therefore, step one here is to make `research_area_category_id` the output of each `CASE` statement, rather than an integer `1`:

```
CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 1994 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END
```

If you ran your code with just this change you would find the `SUM` function causes the output to be multiples of the `research_area_category_id` value. For example, the first row for `1998 - 2002` would have the value `66` (two times 33).

So this tells us you don't want to use the `SUM` function any more. However, you do still want to aggregate (group) the data across all the rows with differing `p_year` values, so you have to use *some* kind of aggregate function instead. If you didn't, SQL Server would throw an error because you're not grouping by `p_year`.

The easiest aggregate function to use in this case is `MAX`, which takes the highest value from the set of rows being grouped up into one. The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) has some straightforward examples.

This will only work in your case provided all values of `research_area_category_id` are positive (greater than the `0` that the `CASE` statement defaults to), which they appear to be.

Combining the change to the `CASE` statements with a change from `SUM` to `MAX` gives the following version of your query:

```
SELECT 
aid, research_area_category_id, 
[research_area] = CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)), 
[Counting] = COUNT(*),
[1990 - 1994] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 1994 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[1992 - 1996] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1992 AND 1996 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[1994 - 1998] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1994 AND 1998 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[1996 - 2000] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[1998 - 2002] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 1998 AND 2002 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[2000 - 2004] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2004 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[2002 - 2006] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2002 AND 2006 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[2004 - 2008] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2004 AND 2008 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[2006 - 2010] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2006 AND 2010 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[2008 - 2012] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2008 AND 2012 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END),
[2010 - 2014] = MAX(CASE WHEN p_year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2014 THEN research_area_category_id ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    sub_aminer_paper
WHERE 
    aid = 2937  
    AND p_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2014            
GROUP BY
    aid, CAST(research_area AS VARCHAR(100)), research_area_category_id
ORDER BY aid ASC, Counting DESC
```

In case you're interested, I mocked up a few rows of data like yours in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28cb6/6) to test this query before answering. (I was guessing at the values of `p_year` but they prove the principle, unless I've misunderstood your requirement.)

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to investigate the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function in Transact-SQL, as this is another approach to displaying results in the style you're after. Whether it's better or worse depends on your use case a lot.

Comment: @philosophicles--Thank you very much, its all amazing with just a function change of SUM to MAX and required column replacement in THEN statement